# how to write a relation with three parameters

Tags: prolog

I want to write a relation in prolog which take three arguments.
Based on the first and second argument, the value should be assigned to the third argument.

for ex: 
CctypeInt is 0..2
relation(CctypeInt,[0-{2,3,4}, 1-{2,3}, 2-{2}],Ru1)

If CctypeInt value is 0 then {2,3,4} shall be assigned to Ru1
If CctypeInt value is 1 then {2,3} shall be assigned to Ru1
If CctypeInt value is 2 then {2} shall be assigned to Ru1

second argument in the list indicates for wchich CCtypeInt value the corresponding list should be assigned.

How can we define a relation with the above behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
relation(CctypeInt,List,Ru1) :-
    member(CctypeInt-Ru1,List).
```

Comment: SO gave you -6 quality score. But it is the perfect answer!